# getting NULL response from IBM MQ

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, mainframe

I am sending a request to IBM MQ and receiving a response using JMS. However, I am currently receiving a null response, even though there is a text message Or byte message present on the mainframe. Can you help me understand why I am getting a null value.

My code is like this.
I declared the username, CICS transaction code, request queue name, and reply queue name before this code."

```
try {
            logger.info("doCicsRequestReply ::: Getting JMS connections  ");
            Hashtable<String, String> environment = new Hashtable<String, String>();

            environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                    "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");

            // Setup JNDI context
            Context context = new InitialContext(environment);

            // Look up connection factory and destination queue
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) context
                    .lookup("jms/MQCF");
            
            // creating request Queue
            Destination requestQueue = (Destination) context
                    .lookup(requestQueueName);

            Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            Session session = connection.createSession(false,
                    Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            logger.info("getJMSConnection:: JMS connections  created ...");

    
            ((JmsDestination) requestQueue).setIntProperty(
                    WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_MESSAGE_CONTEXT,
                    WMQConstants.WMQ_MDCTX_SET_IDENTITY_CONTEXT);
            
            logger.info("doCicsRequestReply: Request  queue created  ");
            
            // creating response queue
            Destination replyQueue = (Destination) context
                    .lookup(replyToQueueName);
            //Destination.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_WRITE_ENABLED, true);

            // closing the context
            context.close();
            // Create connection, session, and producer
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(requestQueue);
            logger.info("doCicsRequestReply: Request and response queue created  ");
            
            // Setting up request headers and message
            BytesMessage message = session.createBytesMessage();
            // Request Headers
            message.setJMSMessageID(MQConstants.MQMI_NONE.toString());
            message.setJMSCorrelationIDAsBytes(MQConstants.MQCI_NEW_SESSION);
            message.setJMSReplyTo(replyQueue);
            message.setStringProperty("JMS_IBM_MQMD_UserIdentifier", racfUserid);
            message.setIntProperty("JMS_IBM_MQMD_CodedCharSetId",
                    CHARSET_IBM500);
            message.setStringProperty("JMS_IBM_MQMD_Format",
                    MQConstants.MQFMT_CICS);
            message.setIntProperty("JMS_IBM_MQMD_Encoding", messageEncoding);
            message.setIntProperty("JMS_IBM_MQMD_Persistence", persistence);

            logger.info("doCicsRequestReply: Request header setup completed.. ");

            byte blanks[] = new byte[8];
            for (int i = 0; i < blanks.length; i++)
                blanks[i] = (byte) ' ';

            // Construct the CIH header as a byte array
            ByteArrayOutputStream outBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream outData = new DataOutputStream(outBytes);

            outData.writeBytes("CIH "); // MQCHAR strucId
            outData.writeInt(2); // MQLONG version
            outData.writeInt(180); // MQLONG strucLength
            outData.writeInt(messageEncoding); // MQLONG encoding
            outData.writeInt(CHARSET_IBM500); // MQLONG CodedCharSetId;
            outData.writeBytes(MQConstants.MQFMT_STRING); // MQCHAR8 Format;
            outData.writeInt(4); // MQLONG Flags;
            outData.writeInt(0); // MQLONG ReturnCode;
            outData.writeInt(0); // MQLONG CompCode;
            //-----continues the remaining code 

            // ---- make sure progName is exactly 8 characters
            StringBuffer pgmName = new StringBuffer(progName);
            for (int i = pgmName.length(); i < 8; i++)
                pgmName.append(' ');
            // ---- write program name followed by commarea
            outData.writeBytes(pgmName.substring(0, 8)); 
            outData.writeBytes(commArea);
            
            logger.info("doCicsRequestReply: Setting byte message..");
            byte[] cihRequestMessage = outBytes.toByteArray();
            message.writeBytes(cihRequestMessage);

            logger.info("doCicsRequestReply: Request body completed");
            logger.info("doCicsRequestReply: Request message:"+outBytes);
            
            // Send the message to queue..
            producer.send(message);
            logger.info("doCicsRequestReply: Request to sent to queue:"+message);
            
            String messageID = message.getJMSMessageID();
            String selector="JMSCorrelationID='"+messageID+"'";
            logger.info("Selecting reply based on selector " + selector);
            // Receive a message from reply queue
            MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(replyQueue,selector);
            //MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(replyQueue);
            logger.info("doCicsRequestReply: create consumer for response... ");
            
            Message replyMessage = consumer.receive(replyTimeout * 1000);

            logger.info("doCicsRequestReply: Response received... : "+replyMessage);

            if(replyMessage==null)
            {
                logger.info("doCicsRequestReply: its a null value... ");
                responseMessage = "null";
            }
            
            else if (replyMessage instanceof TextMessage) {
                
                logger.info(" Reply from CICS server.. TextMessage ");
                String replText = ((TextMessage) replyMessage).getText();
                logger.info(" Reply from CICS server.. " + replText);
                responseMessage = replText;
                
            }else if (replyMessage instanceof BytesMessage) {
                
                logger.info(" Reply from CICS server.. TextMessage ");
                
                BytesMessage bytesMessage = (BytesMessage) replyMessage;
                
                int length = (int) bytesMessage.getBodyLength();
                
                logger.info(" Reply from CICS server.. getBodyLength:: "+length);
                
                byte[] messageBytes = new byte[length];
                
                bytesMessage.readBytes(messageBytes);
                
                String textMessage = new String(messageBytes, "UTF-8");
                
                logger.info(" Reply from CICS server.. " + textMessage);
                
                responseMessage = textMessage;
```

Comment: Where is the code where you create the `connection`?

Comment: `MessageConsumer.receive(long timeout)`: "**Returns:**
    the next message produced for this message consumer, or null if the timeout expires or this message consumer is concurrently closed".

Comment: Because of the IBM migration, the previously used connection pool manager is no longer supported. As a result, I need to identify an alternative approach for sending messages, so I used JMS .so I considering that the old code was sending messages in the following manner.

Comment: And you got a timeout or concurrent close, like it says in the Javadoc I quoted. What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

As you have a time out on `receive`

```
Message replyMessage = consumer.receive(replyTimeout * 1000);
```

`replyMessage` will return `null` after 1 second of waiting, if no message is found.

There are a couple of reasons why a message may not be found.

1. There is no message on the replyTo queue. The reply application hasn't run or it hasn't committed its response.
2. The reply message doesn't have the correlation ID set to the message ID of the original message. You don't share the reply code, so it's difficult to say why.

No message would be found as you have code that has a selector on the correlation ID.

```
String selector="JMSCorrelationID='"+messageID+"'";
logger.info("Selecting reply based on selector " + selector);
// Receive a message from reply queue
MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(replyQueue,selector);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not called [`start()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Connection.html#start--) on the `Connection` to cause messages to flow to your consumer.